# Horizontally center align inline html element

Tags: css

Ok so I have a an anchor element within a div with a fixed width, the anchor element needs to remain inline because the text that it holds is dynamic and it has a background because it is a button. I want the background of the button to only be the size of the length of text too. Is there a way to do so?

```
<div class="wrap">
<a class="button>Start »</a>
</div>



 .wrap{
     width:900px;
background:white;
    }

    a{
    display:inline;
background:black;

    }
```

Comment: And text-align:center on the div won't work? Also, is it an acnhor or is it a button? __a__ elements already have display:inline.

Comment: Set proper `line-height`.

Comment: I want the background of the button to only be the size of the length of text too.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
.wrap{
    width:900px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

will do the trick

See

http://jsfiddle.net/jEsRG/3/

Comment: I want the background of the button to only be the size of the length of text too.

Comment: It should work with the jsfiddle I provided before, but I've updated the example now http://jsfiddle.net/jEsRG/3/